# Why I getting an error while trying to retrieving token from firebase in Vue js?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to implement firebase to my vue.js project but I'm getting error on `firebase.messaging.getToken()`. Here is the screenshot of my problem

[image]

Error:

The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Unable to get permission to notify.

- browserErrorMessage
  :
  "Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html')."
- code
  :
  "messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration"
- message
  :
  "Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html'). (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration)."
- stack
  :
  "FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html'). (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration).↵    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/messaging/dist/index.esm.js:1950:32)"

And here is my code.

```
firebase.messaging().requestPermission().then(function () {
  console.log('Notification permission granted.')
  return firebase.messaging().getToken()
    .then(function (currentToken) {
      console.log(currentToken)
    })
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err)
})
```

Service Workers

[image]

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem? I tried in many ways but i could not figure it out. Can you please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the error as text instead of an image? I don't have my magnifying glass with me so I can't read it.

Comment: Here i added the error as text.

Comment: @Reo93 Can you open Chrome Dev Tools -> Application -> Service Worker and see if you have a service worker that has been registered? If yes click unregister and refresh the page again.

Comment: It is unregistered. I have uploaded the picture in the question.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue of unsupported MIME type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to put the file (or create a file) "**firebase-messaging-sw.js**" inside the **/public** folder

inside the **firebase-messaging-sw.js** copy and paste this (and change **YOUR-SENDER-ID**) :

```
// Give the service worker access to Firebase Messaging.
// Note that you can only use Firebase Messaging here, other Firebase libraries
// are not available in the service worker.
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-messaging.js');

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in the
// messagingSenderId.
firebase.initializeApp({
  'messagingSenderId': 'YOUR-SENDER-ID'
});

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

Worked for me ( using React )

Comment: Putting it inside the /public folder for create-react-app worked for me.